# Existence of numbers coprime within a certain limit

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Let $n=2^km$ be a positive integer with $m$ odd and $r$ the largest prime that divides $m$. Then are there at least $\frac{r-1}{2}$ numbers coprime to $n$ which are less than $r$?

I think yes, but am unable to clearly see it. There are $r-1$ numbers coprime to $r$ less than $r$. But does this translate to half of them being  coprime to $n$? What if I replace $r$ as the largest prime to the smallest prime that divides $n$? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net where do you find the ambiguity?

Comment: Is this true?  Take $n=30=2\times 3\times 5$.  Then $r=5$, yes?  But the only natural number less than $5$ which is prime to $30$ is $1$.

Comment: what if $n=11x9x7x5x2?$

Comment: @abc... thanks, it was so easy!

Answer (score 1):

This is easily seen to be false. Thanks to comment by @abc...  consider the number $n=210=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7$. Then $r$ is $7$ but there are not $3$ numbers that are coprime to $210$ less than $7$